# Python Django check if an attribute exists or has been set

Tags: python, django

I have a `User` object and a `UserInfo` object which have a one to one relationship. I am just adding the `UserInfo` object so some users already have `User` objects but not `UserInfo` objects. I want to check to see if the User object has a UserInfo object associated with it yet and if not redirect them to a page where I can get some info. I am still new to python and have tried doing an `if request.user.user_info:` which throws an exception when it doesn't exist so I ended up doing this:

```
 user = request.user
    try:
        user.user_info.university
    except:
        print 'redirect to info page'
```

which works fine, but I feel like exceptions should be for exceptions and not for if statement substitutes. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try `hasattr(user, 'user_info')` and `'user_info' in user`.

Comment: anothering thing to consider, is if every user should have a `UserInfo` object you could subscribe to user creation signal and initialize a `UserInfo` object automatically for every user created. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say that handling this with exceptions is the pythonic approach. You can do something like this:

```
try:
    # do your thing when user.user_info exists
except AttributeError: # Be explicit with catching exceptions.
    # Redirect.
```

There's a programming concept called  `it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission (EAFP)` which is used extensively in Python. We assume that attributes, keys and so forth exist for a given object and catch exceptions when they do not.

Here are some references and SO questions about EAFP.

[Python glossary](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)
[What is the EAFP principle in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python)
[EAFP and what is really exceptional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086806/python-exceptions-eafp-and-what-is-really-exceptional)

Comment: can also use python hasattr()